# How can I read semicolon separated text out from file and saved into variables

Tags: powershell

I want to get semicolon separated strings out from file while write into var1,var2..
like in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($var1,$var2 in Get-Content ".\list.txt") {
# further processing $var1,$var2 }
```

Comment: `Import-Csv`...

Comment: Why not use "Import-CSV" and work with the object instead?
To define the delimiter use parameter "-Delimiter".

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear you can assign multiple variables as the iterator. But you can take each line and simply split it to the variables inside the loop.

```
$tempfile = New-TemporaryFile

@'
Value1a;Value2b
Value2a;Value2b
'@ | Set-Content -Path $tempfile

foreach($line in Get-Content $tempfile){
    $var1,$var2 = $line -split ';'
    Write-Host First var: $var1 Second var $var2
}
```

Comment: thanks to the **split** in this loop does the job.
`foreach($line in Get-Content ".\list.txt"){
    $user,$pass = $line -split ';' 
New-LocalUser $user -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force)
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a semicolon separated csv file, you can use

```
$csvContent = Import-Csv -Path "list.txt" -Delimiter ";"
```

Afterwards you can work with the $csvContent variable to access the contents .

Comment: This means that the entire content is in one variable, but every line should always be word1;word2 in the variables $var1,$var2

Comment: @DonMatteo learn to use **objects** because this really is the way to go.,